# Can you upload a file in multiple simultaneous chunks to Google Drive via the REST API?

Tags: google-drive-api

An often requested feature for [rclone](https://rclone.org)'s Google drive backend is being able to upload files using multiple chunks at once to speed things up. S3/B2/Box/etc support this so it seems an obvious thing to request for Google Drive.

The closest thing I could find is the Google Drive v3 API [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) feature.

You can use this with with multiple chunks.  I use this API in rclone already, but one chunk at a time.

Reading the docs on that carefully, I think that it can't upload multiple chunks at once - it requires the chunks to be uploaded sequentially, but I'd be delighted to be proved wrong!

> To upload the file in multiple chunks:
>
> 1. Create a PUT request to the resumable session URI.
> 2. Add the chunk's
>      data to the request body. Create chunks in multiples of 256 KB (256 x
>      1024 bytes) in size, except for the final chunk that completes the
>      upload. Keep the chunk size as large as possible so that the upload is
>      efficient.
> 3. Add the following HTTP headers:
>
>    - Content-Length. Set to the number of bytes in the current chunk.
>    - Content-Range: Set to show which bytes in the file you are uploading.
>        For example, Content-Range: bytes 0-524287/2000000 shows that you are
>        uploading the first 524,288 bytes (256 x 1024 x 2) in a 2,000,000 byte
>        file.
> 4. Send the request, and process the response.
>
> If the upload request is interrupted, or if you receive a 5xx
>   response, follow the procedure in Resume an interrupted upload.
>
> 5. Repeat steps 1 through 4 for each remaining chunk in the file. Use the
>      Range header in the response to determine where to start the next
>      chunk. Do not assume that the server received all bytes sent in the
>      previous request.
>
> When the entire file upload is complete, you receive a 200 OK or 201
>   Created response, along with any metadata associated with the
>   resource.

If that API can't do it, is there a different one that can?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the resumable upload of Drive API cannot upload several chunks, simultaneously. And I cannot have thought of other methods for increasing the upload speed, yet. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Although I checked this at the issue tracker, I couldn't find this situation. So I reported this as Feature Request. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132489107 If this is achieved, also I'm glad.